# Comparing two estimators for accuracy using empirical bootstrap

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, bootstrap, paired-comparisons, point-estimation

I am trying to figure out the proper way to compare the quality of two estimators of a parameter based on data. The basic approach I've taken is to compute the MSE of the empirical bootstrap distribution of each estimator, but then **the question is**: how do I put "error bars" on these MSEs, to see if the difference is statistically significant?

**Setup.** I have a parameter $\theta \in \mathbb R$, with a known (to me) true value, and a dataset ${\bf x} = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ that I'm using to estimate $\theta$ using complicated models. In particular, I have have two different estimators, $\hat \theta_A(\cdot)$ and $\hat \theta_B(\cdot)$, that are MLEs for two different models of the data generating process.

**Estimator values.** When I compute the estimates, I get two values, $\hat \theta_A({\bf x})$ and $\hat \theta_B({\bf x})$, and I observe that A is closer than B to the true $\theta$. A great start, but naturally I want to make a robust investigation into wether model A is better than model B.

**Empirical bootstrap distributions.** These estimators are not plausibly normally distributed, and so I'm using bootstrapping to take $m=10000$ sample sets from ${\bf x}$ with replacement, ${\bf x'_1},\ldots, {\bf x'_m}$, and now I have two empirical bootstrap distributions, one for $\hat \theta_A$ and one for $\hat \theta_B$, and a true value, $\theta$.

**MSE**. To compare these two distributions in their proximity to $\theta$, I've computed the mean squared error (MSE) of the bootstrap distribution of $\hat \theta_A$ and of $\hat \theta_B$. This again gives me two numbers, $MSE_A$ and $MSE_B$, and I observe that $MSE_A$ is smaller. Better, but this is still "only a number", and I would prefer a distribution of outcomes, where I could see how often A is better than B. **Question:** is there some proper way to put "error bars" on $MSE_A$ and $MSE_B$?

**Alternative approach: error distributions.** Short of putting error bars on the MSE, my empirical bootstrap distributions are paired, so for each draw of the bootstrap I can compare the two absolute errors $e^A_i = |\hat \theta_A ({\bf x'_i})-\theta|$ to $e^B_i = |\hat \theta_B ({\bf x'_i})-\theta|$, and look at how often one is greater than the other. By looking at the distribution of $\Delta^{A,B}_i = e^A_i - e^B_i$, I can take an empirical 5/95 CI from the bootstrap distribution $\{ \Delta^{A,B}_i, ..., \Delta^{A,B}_m\}$, and notice that, indeed, the 5th percentile is positive.

**Summary questions.** Is this alternative approach a correct way to robustly determine which estimator is better? Is there some basic method for paired tests, with or without bootstrapping, that I should be employing?